# Sort CONCAT values properly MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, concatenation

After performing simple col1/col2 computations and then using `CONCAT` to add a literal `%` sign, I am unable to successfully sort them in order.

Initially my results sorted `DESC` were like

```
9%
8%
75%
65%
100%
```

After an update of:

```
   CASE WHEN ROUND(col1/col2 *100) = 100 
        THEN CONCAT(100, '%') 
        ELSE LPAD(CONCAT(ROUND(col1/col2 *100),'%'),3,'0') 
        END AS Percent
```

I was able to successfully sort the single and double digit columns by adding a 0 in front of the single digit, but i was left with the 100 being out of place

```
75%
65%
09%
08%
100%
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What are you rendering this in?  you should return the decimal value sorted and allow the UI to handle the display format.  The reason this isn't working is a number is now being sorted as character data.  though I'm confused why it's not 75, 65, 100, 09 then 08...  I guess that would depend on how you're doing the sort...

Comment: @xQbert, I am attempting to display the results with a literal % sign as its a conv percentage.

Comment: I understand that; but display it "WHERE" the end user is going to be opearting in the MySQL database? your using PHP to connect and render, Java? asp, jsp, rails??  Whatever that application is that's connecting to the database should read the recordset and then format the output to the proper display.  Now if you just want it displayed that way within mySQL....

Comment: select name, concat(pid,'%') from mytable where condition order by pid desc (and pid is an integer) is working fine in my table. Let's see your DESCRIBE your_table and your SELECT... CONCAT syntax.

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is no problem for which MySQL's CONCAT (or GROUP_CONCAT) functions is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have already added the `%` symbol to the values, so you can retrieve them, without the `%` sign and then sort them and add back the `%` sign. Below is is working and tested SQL example.

```
select concat(percentage, '%') -- add '%' sign
from (
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(percentage, '%', 1) percentage  -- remove `%`
from percentage_sorting) t
order by percentage;  -- order by values
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you convert your percentages to strings you'll basically get alphabetical order, which is normally not what you want for numbers:

```
20%
2%
12%
1%
```

If you want numeric sort, you have to sort on actual numbers:

```
SELECT CONCAT(percentage, '%')
FROM data
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```